# Populate HighChart Data From Rails View

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I've tried a few different things, and this is as close I have been able to get:

```
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function () {
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: { renderTo: 'orders_chart' },
    title: { text: 'Orders by Day' },
    xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
    yAxis: {
      title: { text: 'Dollars' }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function () {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat("%B %e %Y", this.x) + ': ' +
          '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
      }
    },    
    series: [{
      pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
      pointStart: <%= 0.days.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
      data: <%= @daily_count[0] %>
    }]
  });
});
</script>
```

The problem is specifically: `data: <%= @daily_count[0] %>` this currently gives me one datapoint. I've tried just `<%= @daily_count %>` but that doesn't work. What I need is a way to put an array, and specifically `[daily_count[0], daily_count[1]...]` into data.

Comment: what is the content of @daily_count

Comment: It's an array that might look like this [1,2,3,8,2..].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `to_json`

```
data: <%= @daily_count.to_json %>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it needs to be `<%= ... %>` as other examples use that format. If I remove the `=` I get the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } ` Nothing at all in the rails error logs or javascript console otherwise.

Comment: @NoahClark, what is the value of `<%= @daily_count.to_json %>` after the page loads?

Comment: `data: [ <% @daily_count.each do |d|%><%= d.inspect %><%end%>]` makes it work.

Comment: I was creating a bad array, with each element inside it's own array. Once I reworked that `.to_json` worked as well.

Comment: Sorry, about the bad error message "it doesn't work". Maybe I shouldn't try to program with a fever :)

Comment: @NoahClark, never mind we all have our bad day.. I have often ;)